# How do I use "not rlike" in spark-sql?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

`rlike` works fine but `not rlike` throws an error:

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("select * from T where columnB rlike '^[0-9]*$'").collect()
res42: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([412,0], [0,25], [412,25], [0,25])

scala> sqlContext.sql("select * from T where columnB not rlike '^[0-9]*$'").collect()
java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.35] failure: ``in'' expected but `rlike' found


val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (412, 0),
  (0, 25), 
  (412, 25), 
  (0, 25)
)).toDF("columnA", "columnB")
```

Or it is continuation of issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4207 ?

Comment: Can you negate your regular expression and just use `rlike` instead of `not rlike`?

Comment: As @doelleri said, the next thing to try is `not (columnB rlike '^[0-9]*$')` or similar. (No idea if parentheses would be optional. Depends on the language.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing as such not rlike, but in regex you have something called negative lookahead, which means it will give the words that does not match.

For above query, you can use the regex as below. Lets say, you want the ColumnB should not start with digits '0'

Then you can do like this.

```
sqlContext.sql("select * from T where columnB rlike '^(?!.*[1-9]).*$'").collect() 
Result: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([412,0])
```

What I meant over all is, you have to do with regex it self to negate the match, not with rlike. Rlike simply matches the regex that you asked to match. If your regex tells it to not match, it applies that, if your regex is for matching then it does that.

Answer (score 17):

A concise way to do it in PySpark is:

```
df.filter(~df.column.rlike(pattern))
```

Comment: our unsung hero! this should be the accepted answer, but it was asked so long ago :)

Answer (score 4):

The above answers suggests to use a negative lookahead. It can be achieved for some cases. However regexps were not designed to make an effecient negative match.
Those regexp will be error prone and hard to read.

Spark does support "not rlike" since version 2.0.

```
 # given 'url' is column on a dataframe
 df.filter("""url not rlike "stackoverflow.com"""")
```

The only usage known to me, is a sql string expression (as above). I could not find a "not" sql dsl function in the python api. There might be one in scala.

Answer (score 3):

I know your question is getting a bit old, but just in case : have you simply tried scala's unary "!" operator?

In java you would go something like that :

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.table("T");
DataFrame notLikeDf = df.filter(
  df.col("columnB").rlike("^[0-9]*$").unary_$bang()
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In pyspark, I did this as :

```
df = load_your_df()

matching_regex = "yourRegexString"

matching_df = df.filter(df.fieldName.rlike(matching_regex))

non_matching_df = df.subtract(matching_df)
```